# Main app's icons overlays in Nova Prime's widgets

Tags: 8.0-oreo, nova-launcher, overlay, motorola-moto-z2-play

I've been using Nova Prime for about 5 years, which includes doing at least 10-20 settings backup-and-restore on various devices.

Today I made one another (on my Motorola Moto Z2 Play / Android 8.0 Oreo) and to my extreme surprise I have noticed that all my (restored) contacts widgets have a nasty "main" app (i.e. Contacts) icon overlay over each my contact's photo.

Picture worth thousand words -- before (left) sending Z2 to repair and after getting it back (right):

[image]

Analysis so far:

- the problem is only with Contacts; other widgets (Wikipedia and Fancy Widgets in my case) have no "main" app icon overlay,
- happens on both widgets restored from Nova Prime's backup and freshly added,
- happens on Motorola Moto Z2 only (i.e. does not happen on Motorola One),
- happens on Motorola Moto Z2 only this time (starting from this backup restore), since I hadn't this problem for past half year, prior to sending this phone for a repair.

Questions:

- does anyone else experiences similar problem?
- what is its source: is it caused by recent change to Contacts or Nova Prime?
- is there any workaround or a way to get rid of this nasty little thing?

I am adding a contact-shortcut widget by:

- opening Contacts app (default app under 8.0 Oreo?),
- finding given contact and tapping it to get to details,
- tapping three-dot and selecting *Create shortcut* from menu.

The only difference that I noticed is that prior to this backup restore (prior to sending my Moto Z2 for a repair and getting it back) and on every other device I am getting shortcut created right after above (right after tapping *Create shortcut*). While this time and on this Moto Z2 I see some new, additional *Add to Home screen* window, where I have to tap *Add*.

I assume (given above) that the problem's source is Nova Prime, not Contacts app.

I am using Motorola Moto Z2 Play (XT-1710-09) with Nova Prime 6.0 on board Android 8.0 Oreo.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.androidcentral.com/developers-must-read-get-your-apps-ready-android-os-new-shortcuts-and-widgets%3famp . It is known as app pinned short cut. If we create an app's shortcut, shortcut contain small app icon(here it will be contacts icon) on bottom right.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any explanation for the first point in my analysis list, i.e. why other app's widgets aren't affected by this problem? Or what is the difference between pinned app shortcut and regular widget, if both are added in Nova Prime the very same way, but only Contacts (and not Wikipedia / Fancy Widgets in my case) are affected?

Comment: On the left, the device may be running in android 7.0 and 7.1+ higher the above feature(pinned shortcut) is implemented first. And, currently your device is running in 8.0 Oreo. Its not related with Nova launcher, default android launcher(AOSP/Pixel) have such features, and Nova launcher's dev's apply such features to Nova launcher to make it nearly stock android like pixel.

Comment: No, I am using two different devices (Samsung Galaxy J9 and Motorola Moto Z2) and you are correct that Samsung has Android 7.1 while Motorola has Samsung 8.0, but -- as I wrote in my question -- these two screens comes from the same device (Motorola) before (left) and after (right) repair. Could it be possible that before sending phone to the repair it was running Android 7.1 and never actually updated itself OTA to Android 8.0, but while being in repair it was force-updated by repair shop stuff to Android 8.0? And that's the explanation while I have noticed these overlays only right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is its source: is it caused by recent change to Contacts or Nova Prime?

Rahul in [comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208806/main-apps-icons-overlays-in-nova-primes-widgets#comment267801_208806) has pointed the reason (thanks Rahul). It is an OS feature introduced from Oreo (and the likely reason you didn't see it earlier- service folks must have upgraded it while under repair). For more see [Android Developers : shortcuts overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts)

> is there any workaround or a way to get rid of this nasty little thing?

Long press on shortcut → edit → long press on photo →select theme  → Gallery apps → select photos and choose the contact photo, go back  → Done

A disadvantage is that you have a rectangular icon that won't match with other icon appearance . But that may be good too to differentiate contact shortcuts!

I don't know how to fix that, unless you use a photo editor app that gives you round shapes (OP has suggested - you can use [this Ukrainian on-line tool](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/crop-photo-into-various-shapes.php) or [this Russian on-line tool](http://www.oooo.plus/en/crop.php) or [search for some alternative](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+circle+photos+online&oq=create+circle+photos+online&aqs=chrome..69i57.4719j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).

And it is not for contacts only. I have a mail app which shows the same for "compose" shortcut. This app is targeted for min sdk 28 (Oreo). From August this year, all [apps have to target Oreo](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) and you will see this behavior uniformly

Tested on the latest version of Nova on Pie.

Comment: In my case it is only Contacts. Maybe because this is the only widget that I use in 1x1 size on my screen. For 5x1 Wikipedia widget and for 2x5 Fancy Widgets weather widget there is no overlay. Just a note.

Comment: But, either I am getting something wrong or this is some kind of "shifting" feature. My wife has Motorola One with Nova Prime 6.0 (newest) and Android 9.0 Pie (newest as well) and does not have this problem (no icon overlays on Contacts-shortcuts widgets).

Comment: I'm running Motorola Moto X4 Android 9.0, while creating shortcut of contacts app, it will display contact app-icon on bottom-right corner.

Comment: @RahulGopi : Thanks for the link (saved me trouble of searching). Credited in answer

Comment: @trejder: I have no idea why it is not happening on your wife's phone (third party contact app is one possibility). I know and have seen it on other devices running on Oreo. As to why it doesn't happen on her phone could be a separate question, with this one linked as background

Comment: FWIW, the app icon on the app *shortcuts* (not widgets, they're different and don't show app icon) also appears on my Nexus 5, Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1 Nougat) on Pixel Launcher. Also, [it's first introduced on Android 7.1](https://medium.com/@andreworobator/implementing-android-app-shortcuts-74feb524959b) //cc @trejder

Comment: @AndrewT. Can we, from your comment and my info that I hadn't this problem before, actually assume that source of problem is Contacts app changing "shortcuts" to contacts from regular widgets (previously, no overlay) to app shortcuts (today, overlay)?

Comment: @trejder now that I think about it, there's a possibility of that case considering some apps (like Contacts) have both widgets (for backward compatibility) and shortcuts (for newer OS) that have the same function.